# How to make release using rebar without erts?

Tags: erlang, rebar

How to make release using rebar without erts included in?

Comment: I created example project to show how to build erlang application without erts: http://sinnus.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-make-release-without-erts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A release **is** a self packaged erlang runtime within your application, so i think you just can't.

But you can simply give your application directory with the ebin directory in it as a release.

Answer (score 1):

rebar is a good thing for managing your Erlang prjects indeed. But there are always other options which comes for Erlanf/OTP in the box. Here you can read very good tutorial about other options: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/release-is-the-word

p.s. I think it is worth knowing how the same thing could be done in other way.

Answer (score -1):

Relx is very good at packaging Erlang releases with lots of options, one being what you want: {include_erts, false}.

https://github.com/erlware/relx